How do I enter a set of characters without pressing Enter in Golang CLI application?
The task is to pass the string to the function read by the barcode scanner without pressing ENTER. That is, the terminal should not wait as in the case of bufio.New Scanner.Scan() but immediately send the read string for processing.
I've tried a lot of options, but nothing works, the console is waiting for you to press Enter. Here is one of the latest versions:
package main

import (
    "bufio"
    "fmt"
    "log"
    "os"

    "golang.org/x/term"
)

func main() {
    state, err := term.MakeRaw(int(os.Stdin.Fd()))
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatalln("setting stdin to raw:", err)
    }
    defer func() {
        if err := term.Restore(int(os.Stdin.Fd()), state); err != nil {
            log.Println("warning, failed to restore terminal:", err)
        }
    }()

    in := bufio.NewReader(os.Stdin)

    l, _, err := in.ReadLine()
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Printf("error: %v\r\n", err)
    }
    fmt.Printf("read line %v\r\n", l)

}

And I tried it like this:
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "log"
    "os"

    "golang.org/x/term"
)

func main() {
    var (
        line string
        quit bool
        err  error
    )

    // setup terminal
    oldState, err := term.MakeRaw(int(os.Stdin.Fd()))
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatalln("setting stdin to raw:", err)
    }
    defer func() {
        if err := term.Restore(int(os.Stdin.Fd()), oldState); err != nil {
            log.Println("warning, failed to restore terminal:", err)
        }
    }()

    term := term.NewTerminal(os.Stdin, "> ")

    for err == nil && !quit {
        line, err = term.ReadLine()
        if err != nil {
            break
        }

        if string(line) == "q" {
            quit = true
        }
    }

    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err)
    }

    if quit {
        fmt.Println("Quitting...")
    }
}

What should I do?

The question is not clear to me: Do you want to send each character one by one to your function for immediate processing (which means that your function should ideally be in its own thread), or do you want to collect a certain numer of characters, and then send them to your function?

@user1934428 Yes, the problem is that the barcode scanner already transmits a set of characters, so it is impractical to parse the string into characters, if the characters arrived one at a time, then I can handle the runes, but in this case it does not work that way

You are trying to use things called "ReadLine", which by definition will scan until reaching a line ending character, but you're also trying to avoid entering a \n which would be that line ending character. Since you've already put the terminal in raw mode, just read directly from stdin.

hmmm ... @JimB just term.Read?

That package doesn't have a Read or ReadRune method. You can just read directly from stdin if you're not concerned about maintaining a consistent display in the terminal. Otherwise you need to go to something with more low-level access (or write it yourself), like ncurses or a readline library.

Maybe it is not very practical, but if you need to read n characters in raw mode, I think the most reasonable approach would be t read n times a single character and build up your n-character string from this.

@user1934428 thinking about it
